# C# Client - route chooser

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have the following DTO

```
[Route("/Locations/{Code}/ToLocal/{Datetime}")]
[Route("/Locations/{Code}/ToUTC/{Datetime}")]
public class TimeConvertToLocal : IReturn<TimeConvertResponse>
{
.....
```

And use the C# client this way:

```
var result = client.Get(new TimeConvert()
{                                    
    Code = 'ABC',
    Datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")
});
```

It work but always choose the `ToUTC` route. How should I tell the client to choose the `ToLocal` route? Or should I change my implementation and split this into two `DTOs`?

Comment: Your client should always send dates as their local time. I assume you have a lookup based on the client locale. If you do not store the clients locale then you need another method to send in the locale of the client. With the locale then you can perform the calcs you are after.

Comment: Thank you but not really my question. I just want to know how I can tel the ServiceStack C#client to use the "ToLocal" or the "ToUTC" route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another variable to your route. Something like Route("/Locations/{Code}/{Format}/{Datetime}") and have the client specify.

Since you named the class TimeConvertToLocal, you may also just consider creating a new request DTO TimeConvertToUTC.

Or lastly, just provide both answers to the client and let them pick the one they want. Ex: Route("/Locations/{Code}/{Datetime}") and your response would contain both Local and UTC times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mike - indeed we ended up doing exactly your first solution but will change to the second one as it is more elegant.